# Getting slider data in template

Tags: django, carousel

I need slider in my website and I have tried these things as mentioned below but I cannot get the data from the database in template. Is the process of getting data from database is wrong. How to get the data in template I am really confused how to do these things.

Model.py

```
class AddImage(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    publish=models.BooleanField(default=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    slider_img=AddImage.objects.all()
    context = {

        'slider_img':slider_img
    }
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

home.html

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
 {% for img in slider_img %}
 {% if img.publish %}
  <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ img.image.url }" alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change `{{ img.image.url }` to `{{ img.image.url }}`, you are missing a closing braces.

Comment: but also still not working.....

Comment: are you getting anything? like Next, Previous text?

Comment: aha no nothing..

Comment: maybe your if condition is failing, also can you check if CSS is hiding that content?

Comment: try this <p>{{ img.image.url }}</p>, check if this prints anything. and also put something in "else" part for this {% if img.publish %}

Comment: <p>{{ img.image.url }}</p> these syntax is also not working..

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Check your settings.py, that you have defined MEDIA_ROOT and 'MEDIA_URL' (and they are correct).

> And add these lines to the end of your urls.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Try to print the data in {{ img.image.url }}, like <p>{{ img.image.url }}</p>